# Recursive Exponent Method stack overflow

Tags: java, recursion, exponent

I already searched everywhere for a solution for my problem, but didn't get one. So what I'm trying to do ist use recursion to find out whats a passed integer variable's base to the power of the passed exponent. So for example 3² is 9. My solution really looks like what I found in these forums, but it **constantly gives me a stack overflow error**. Here is what I have so far.(To make it easier, I tried it with the ints directly not using scanner to test my recursion) Any idea?

```
public class Power {
   public static int exp(int x,int n) {        
      n = 3;
      x = 2;

      if (x == 0) {
         return 1;
      }
      else { 
         return n * exp(n,x-1);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {                           
      System.out.println(exp(2,3));
   }
}
```

Comment: You have confused `x` and `n` and swapped them around.  I suggest you give them meaningful names.

Comment: Each time you call that method, no matter what you pass through, x will == 2. Your method will never exit, because x will never be 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've got three problems.

First, inside of the method, you're reassigning `x` and `n`.  So, regardless of what you pass in, `x` is always 2, and `n` is always 3.  This is the main cause of your infinite recursion - as far as the method is concerned, those values never update. Remove those assignments from your code.

Next, your base case is incorrect - you want to stop when `n == 0`.  Change your `if` statement to reflect that.

Third, your recursive step is wrong.  You want to call your next method with a reduction to `n`, not to `x`.  It should read `return x * exp(x, n-1);` instead.

Comment: And the `else` is redundant. In fact, it's safe to say that there isn't a single _correct_ line of code here...

Comment: okay I did what you said @Makoto my code does now look like this:
`if (n == 0) {
     return 1;
      }
      
      return n * exp(x,n-1);`but what I get is 24 when I pass 4²

Comment: Revised answer.  It should be `x * exp(x, n-1)`.

Comment: @mxfilerelatedcache one lesson to learn here is to use **proper variable names** not `x` and `n`.

Comment: @Boris the Spider I know, thanks anyways. We had to use x and n in this exercise for university.